# angular 2 transient providers instead of singleton

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, websocket, signalr

I have provider which I would like to act as transient instead of a singleton.  I know I can create object manually but I would like to still resolve dependencies through the dependency injector.

```
export class HubServiceBase {

    private readonly hubAuthorizationQueryParameter = 'authToken';

    onCreate = new EventEmitter<any>();
    connectionEstablished = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
    connectionExists = false;

    private _hubConnection: any;

    constructor(public authManager: AuthenticationProvider) {            
    }

    initialize(hubSubRoute: string): void{
        const accessToken = this.authManager.getRawAccessToken();

        let hubUrl = environment.baseUrl + hubSubRoute;
        if (accessToken) {
            hubUrl += '?' + this.hubAuthorizationQueryParameter +'=' + accessToken;
        }

        this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                                .withUrl(hubUrl)
                                .build();
    }
//...
}
```

the initialize function can be called from different services and it maintains a web socket with my server.  There can be multiple sockets open running concurrently.

How can I get a new one from the Dependency injector each time a page requests it?

Comment: configure it on the components `providers` property

Comment: @vikas, how can I do this while leverage the Dependency Injector?

Comment: While reading the question it was looking like something different (as per the question its not easy to understand) that what you actually want!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `providers` property in the `@Component` decorator.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'selector-name',
  templateUrl: './template.component.html',
  providers: [ SomeService ]
})
```

Docs (not great): https://angular.io/api/core/Component

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-vewqis?file=app%2Fhello-framework%2Fcomponents%2Fcounter%2Fcounter.component.ts

Comment: Thanks that looks like it will work, I wish there was a better explaination in the docs though

Comment: Yeah I was pretty disappointed by the documentation - it is a circular reference between Directive and Component even if you are looking for it directly.

Comment: yeah Vikas provided a nice version of the documentation which explains  the scope in providing services link,  but you answered with an example first so I marked you the check, If would be so kind you up vote his answer as well so I don't feel so guilty ;)

Comment: Sounds like a deal ;)

Comment: Thanks!! I had my DataSource registered as provider on the Module and since it was injected as a singleton the BehaviourSubject inside was completed and not re-instantiated another run :-)

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 6):

you can configure injectors in Angular by:

1. providers on `NgModule`.
2. providers on `Components`

If you want an instance of a dependency to be shared globally and share state across the application you configure it on the `NgModule`.-*Singleton*

If you want a separate instance of a dependency to be shared across each instance of a component and it’s children you configure it on the components `providers` property.*Non-singleton*

**[`Providing services`](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services)**

 **[`Angular's Hierarchical Dependency Injection system`](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)**